# Python dataset calculations

Tags: python

I have a data set recording different weeks and the new cases of dengue for that specific week and I am supposed to calculate the infection rate and recovery rate for each week. The infection rate can be calculated by dividing the number of newly infected patients by the susceptible population for that week while the recovery rate can be calculated by dividing the number of newly recovered patients by the infected population for that week. The infection rate is relatively simple but for the recovery rate I have to take into account that infected patients take exactly 2 weeks to recover and I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated

```
t_pop = 4*10**6
s_pop = t_pop
i_pop = 0
r_pop = 0
weeks = 0

#Infection Rate
for index, row in data.iterrows():
    new_i = row['New Cases']
    s_pop -= new_i
    weeks += 1
    infection_rate = float(new_i)/float(s_pop)
    print('Week', weeks, ':' ,infection_rate)
```

*Note: t_pop refers to total population which we assume to be 4million, s_pop refers to the population at risk of contracting dengue and i_pop refers to infected population

Comment: This is a valid question, but it isn't machine learning per se, is it...

Comment: @icedwater part of a larger question about machine learning

Comment: For easy (rectangular) data manipulation take a look to python pandas. It has a function called `shift` that might help you further: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html

Comment: @Tim but what I need now is to find a way to factor in the fact that patients take 2 weeks to recover into the recovery rate and not so much of shifting the dataset

Comment: @icedwater any suggestions?

Comment: Not really, I just came here to say that this is more mathematics than machine learning per se - since you have new cases per week, wouldn't the recovery rate just be the new cases from 2 weeks ago? (Edit: divided by the infected population that week, of course.)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary to store the data for each week, and then use it to refer back to when you need to calculate the recovery rate.  For example:

```
dengue_dict = {}
dengue_dict["Week 1"] = {"Infection Rate": infection_rate, "Recovery Rate": None}
```

I use none at first, because there's no recovery rate until at least two weeks have gone by.  Later, you can either update weeks or just add them right away.  Here's an example for week 3:

```
recovery_rate = dengue_dict["Week 1"]["Infection Rate"]/infection_rate
```

And then update the entry in the dictionary:

```
dengue_dict["Week 3"]["Recovery Rate"] = recovery_rate
```